# Using large sparse DICT as a cache?

Tags: python, dictionary, caching, sparse-matrix

I use large Dict as a cache.
The structure is { string : float }

This is very sparse dict i.e. majority of float entries are zero.

I'm  looking for technique to 'consolidate' somehow the zero-kv to save memory, but the speed for access has to stay approx the same /otherwise i would have used redis or db/.

The cache hit ~40ns saves me ~100-200ms function call.

i already use sys.intern()

Any trick or technique that could work.

---

may be this will work : https://github.com/KeyviDev/keyvi

KV store that uses FSM to compress keys with similar values

Comment: Can you assume that any string not in the dict has a float of 0 or do you also need to keep track of which strings are in the dict vs. which arent? Cause I'd just do `cache.get('string', 0.0)` if you can assume anything not in the dict is 0.

Comment: no.. that is the reason i add them in the cache.. possible string keys are almost infinite

Comment: Then no - this is already most efficient (the python interpreter will just reuse the same immutable `0.0` anyway, it shouldn't keep millions of them in memory). Actually as I write that I'm not sure it works for floats; maybe just keep them as integer 0s instead of float 0.0s.